# Block.timestamp returning multiple values

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, timestamp

I have a function inside my smart contract that fetches the timestamp of the block it's in:

```
function getTime() public returns (uint256 time){
    return block.timestamp;;
}
```

According to how I understand timestamps, this should return one value. Yet when I deploy the contract and test that method it returns two values:

```
truffle(development)> contract.getTime.call({from: accounts[1]})
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 41810542, 23, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 2,
  red: null
}
```

Why is this happening/ what do the two values represent if only one of them is the timestamp?

Comment: where do you see two numbers?

Comment: Inside the array labeled words - I see 41810542 and 23 in addition to the length being equal to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `BN` stands for BigNumber. It's a JavaScript framework for representing..well...big numbers.

If you simply `console.log` a `BigNumber` it will give you such internal data of the single BigNumber, such as those `length` and `words`. Those are not trivially interpretable.

So what you should do it simply `.toString()` it to get the actual number. It really is just one number and what you are now seeing is an object representation of the single number. Here's some more info: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/70926/31933

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much!